# Copy value of one item from a list into another in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, pagination

NET, I need to copy the values of an object item in one list into another list, this is what i have:

```
List<Business> businesses; // from where I want to copy the value
PaginationResult<Business> paginatedBusinesses // contains the final list
```

The type paginated result has a list inside it:

```
public class PaginationResult<T>
{
    public PaginationResult();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     This is the collection of paged items
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
```

The Business object contains these attributes:

```
    public class Business : IAggregateRoot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifier of the business
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// The epoch timestamp this user last accessed this business.
    /// </summary>
    public long? LastAccessed { get; set; }
```

Here i converted the items of the paginatedBusiness list into the Business class:

```
var paginatedBusinesses = results.ConvertItems<Business>((i) => i.ToDomainEntity());
```

I need to copy the LastAccessed values from the *businesses* list into *paginatedBusinesses.Items.* searching for the Id (both lists have the id with the same values but in the first we have the LastAccessed value and in the final list we don't have it). How can I do it? I tried with something like:

```
paginatedBusinesses.Items.AddRange(businesses.Select(i => i.LastAccessed));
```

But it does not work, how can i put it in the object that correspond (the one that have the same id), also i tried with a foreach but not sure how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [`.Select(i => i.<T>)` will produce an `Enumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) so it looks like you're attempting to put a collection of `long` inside of a collection of `Business`. What is your expected result here? Do you want a list of `long` or a list of businesses?

Comment: Hi @DekuDesu i want a list of Businesses (both list are from the same object) so i need to copy the LastAccessed value from one list into the other (which this value is null)

Comment: Previously i converted the paginatedBusines like this: 
var paginatedBusinesses = results.ConvertItems<Business>((i) => i.ToDomainEntity());

Comment: The thing here is that I have to search for the Id of each item in the list to pass the LastAccessed to the one that corresponds to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly: both the `pagenatedBusinesses.Items` and the `businesses` lists contain `Business` objects with the same Ids.

**The question:** *How do I copy the `LastAccessed` values from items in the `businesses` list to items in the `pagenatedBusinesses.Items` list that have the same `Id`?*

If that is correct then the following code will copy the `LastAccessed` value from the `Business` objects in the `businesses` list into the `Business` objects with the same `Id` in the `pagenatedBusinesses.Items` list:

```
paginatedBusinesses.Items
    .Join(
        businesses, 
        p => p.Id, b => b.Id, 
        (p, b) => new {PagenatedBusiness = p, b.LastAccessed})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => i.PagenatedBusiness.LastAccessed = i.LastAccessed);
```